# Change fragments depending on int value

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Hello everyone I have a problem with my code, what I want to do is that when you change the spinner position change the fragments to display, here is what I've written, but it doesn't work, if someone could please give me a better way to do it or a solution it would be great!

This is my class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private static final int NUM_PAGES = 2;

private ViewPager mPager;
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
String[] ciudades = { "Desde Paraná", "Desde Santa Fe", "Desde el pozo", "Desde abogacia"};
public int ciudad = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( this, R.array.opciones, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp.setAdapter(adapter);

    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

                ciudad = position;
                Toast.makeText(parentView.getContext(), ciudades[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

        }
    });

    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        // Otherwise, select the previous step.
        mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    }
}


private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    /* Here is what I do, I took the value of ciudad and use it to display different group of fragment */
        if(ciudad == 0){
            switch(position){
                case 0:
                    return new Home_fragment();
                case 1:
                    return new Next_fragment();                 
            }
        }else if(ciudad == 1){
            switch(position){
                case 0:
                    return new Home_fragment_staFe();
                case 1:
                    return new Next_fragment_staFe();                   
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I've tried what kcoppock tell me to use

> notifyDataSetChanged()

And I used like this, but it still not working

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());



    Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( this, R.array.opciones, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp.setAdapter(adapter);

    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

                ciudad = position;
                Toast.makeText(parentView.getContext(), ciudades[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

        }
    });

    // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

}
```

Comment: `"but it doesn't work"` Please never use that to describe a problem. What doesn't work?

Comment: When I change the ciudad value doesn't change from Home_fragment() to Home_fragment_staFe()

Answer (score 0):

It's never going to call getItem() again as it doesn't know the value of `ciudad` has changed. In your spinner value changed method, when you change the value of `ciudad`, call `mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to notify the adapter that it should recreate the Fragments.

Also, `Home_fragment` is a very unconventional naming pattern for Java. It should instead be `HomeFragment`.